# Is there any transcript of the talking in the Astartes video series?

Tags: warhammer-40k

There isn't a lot of talking in the series, but at one point the spheres appear to be talking to each other. It is difficult for me to make out what they are saying, if anything, so I was wondering if they are talking and if so has anyone made a transcript?

Comment: Is this it?    https://www.reddit.com/r/40kLore/comments/fw3ikk/sphere_bros_conversation_on_astartes_part_5/

Comment: "Gives the veteran sergeant a warning"... yes. very accurate lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google found this for me on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/40kLore/comments/fw3ikk/sphere_bros_conversation_on_astartes_part_5/):

> 4:03 Orb1 "Who is here?"
>
> 4:05 Orb2 "I have failed you, brother" (couldn't stop the marines or
> corrupt them)
>
> 4:08 Orb1 "We have all failed" (he's captured)
>
> 4:11 Orb1 "The Astartes defy our touch" (they have a hard time
> controlling them)
>
> 4:15 Orb2 "You must return... Break your seal!" (returning from the
> warp to "normal" universe and get free from the inquisitors seal)
>
> 4:19 Orb1 "Impossible we'll never survive!"
>
> 4:23 Orb2 "You must take the alpha" (the inquisitor since he's the
> highest ranked and has psyker powers he is the "Alpha" if the Daemon
> controls him he has the entire ship.)
>
> Orb 2 is the spiked one.  Orb 1 is being sealed by the inquisitor.  The
> spike are a communication device to force link them within the warp so
> the inquisitor can listen to their conversation.